# Get the client bound IP address with an Axis2 Server with multi NIC

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm connecting to an Axis 2 Server through a stub :

```
MyServiceStub fcc = new MyServiceStub(url);
```

once the connection is established, since I have different IP address configured on the machine on different subnet, I want to know what is the address that got the connection  with the server .

For example if I have a machine with 2 NIC and IP address configured in this way :

```
eth0 ---> 192.165.0.1
eth1 ---> 10.0.3.1
```

and I have an Axis server on the IP : 10.0.3.33, once the connection is established, how can I know the bounded IP address ?

How can I get the connected client IP address (in this case : `10.0.3.1`) ?

Comment: put in answer but i am not sure at 100%

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this

```
request.getHeader("url");
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
   if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https protocol to invoke axis2 web service, you can implements your own SecureProtocolSocketFactory like this:

```
public class CustomProtocolSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("trace");
    InetAddress localAddress=null;
    SSLContext ctx=null;
    Socket socket=null;
    public CustomProtocolSocketFactory(SSLContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    public CustomProtocolSocketFactory(SSLContext ctx, InetAddress localAddress) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.localAddress=localAddress;
    }
    public CustomProtocolSocketFactory(SSLContext ctx, InetAddress localAddress, Socket socket) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.localAddress=localAddress;
        this.socket=socket;
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        logger.debug("createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort)");
        return ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
            HttpConnectionParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        logger.debug("createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,HttpConnectionParams params)");
        if (params == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters may not be null");
        }
        int timeout = params.getConnectionTimeout();
        SocketFactory socketfactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        if (timeout == 0) {
            if(this.localAddress!=null){
                return socketfactory.createSocket(host, port, this.localAddress, localPort);
            }
            else{
                return socketfactory.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
            }
        } else {
            Socket socket = socketfactory.createSocket();
            if(this.localAddress!=null){
                SocketAddress localaddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.localAddress, localPort);
                SocketAddress remoteaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                socket.bind(localaddr);
                socket.connect(remoteaddr, timeout);
                return socket;
            }
            else{
                SocketAddress localaddr = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
                SocketAddress remoteaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                socket.bind(localaddr);
                socket.connect(remoteaddr, timeout);
                return socket;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        if(localAddress!=null){
            logger.debug("createSocket(String host, int port) localAddress not null");
            return createSocket(host, port, localAddress, 0);
        }
        else{
            logger.debug("createSocket(String host, int port)");
            return ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        logger.debug("createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)");
        return ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }
}
```

in a way that you can bind the socket with InetAddress localAddress and use like this:

```
proxy._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER,
                            new Protocol("https",(ProtocolSocketFactory)new CustomProtocolSocketFactory(context,localAddress),port));
```

Comment: How can you extract the connected IP address ? The question was : I have two ip addresses, and I want to know which one connected to the axis web server